# C++11 set range based for using structs as elements

Tags: c++11, set, range

Let's say I have a struct like this:

```
struct Something{
    string name;
    int code;
};
```

And a set of Something type:

```
set<Something> myset;
myset.insert({"aaa",123,});
myset.insert({"bbb",321});
myset.insert({"ccc",213});
```

What's wrong with this?

```
for (auto sth : myset){
       cout << sth.name;
       cout << sth.code;
}
```

Along the same lines... why can't I modify an element (even when the set contains plain int items) using something like this?

```
for (auto &sth : myset){
       sth=[some value];
}
```

I know I can do this with vectors and maps. Why not sets?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Modifying an element of a set implies its position in the set's order can change. Because your compiler cannot know what exactly a particular set uses to determine its element's orders. Well, it could, theoretically, but even then it would be nearly impossible to keep track of the rearrangements while iterating through the container. It would make no sense.

What you can do, if you want to modify the elements of a set in such a way that you know will not change their order in a set, you can make the non-ordering members of your struct mutable. Note that if you make a mistake and the set's order is disturbed, any other operations on the set (like a binary search) will give incorrect results after that faulty modification. If you don't want to make members mutable, const_cast is an option, with the same caveats.

---

To elaborate on my answer above, an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct bla
{
  std::string name;
  int index;
};

bool operator<(const bla& left, const bla& right) { return left.index < right.index; }

int main()
{
  std::set<bla> example{{"har", 1}, {"diehar", 2}};

  // perfectly fine
  for(auto b : example)
    std::cout << b.index << ' ' << b.name << '\n';

  // perfectly fine - name doesn't influence set order
  for(auto& b : example) // decltype(b) == const bla&
    const_cast<std::string&>(b.name) = "something";

  // better than first loop: no temporary copies
  for(const auto& b : example)
    std::cout << b.index << ' ' << b.name << '\n';

  // using a "universal reference auto&&", mostly useful in template contexts
  for(auto&& b : example) // decltype(b) == const bla&
    std::cout << b.index << ' ' << b.name << '\n';

  // destroying order of the set here:
  for(auto& b : example)
    const_cast<int&>(b.index) = -b.index;

  // anything here relying on an ordered collection will fail
  // This includes std::set::find, all the algorithms that depend on uniqueness and/or ordering

  // This is pretty much all that will still work, although it may not even be guaranteed
  for(auto&& b : example)
    std::cout << b.index << ' ' << b.name << '\n';
}
```

[Live code on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bbc4669a7b6a4ccd).

Note the first `const_cast` is only ok because the underlying `example` isn't `const` in the first place.

Comment: Thanks! I see now. And what about the first part? I'm not modifying the elements, just trying to read them, only that they are members of a struct. Why isn't that allowed?

Comment: You should be able to use constant auto& of The generally applicable auto&& to do that. Although taking a copy should work too let me check...

Comment: I see, so I definitely need to overload < within my object. However, I don't understand why I can't even modify a primitive type like int. Let's say myset is an **unordered_set** containing plain _int_ items; I still get an error saying the object is read-only when I try `for (auto &sth : myset) if (sth==2) {sth=0;}` If I just change unordered_set type to vector it compiles seamlessly. I'm confused.

Comment: You're not getting an error about a read-only object. If there's concrete code, there's concrete errors. Booth of which you are not showing. Everything else from my side is speculation and guesswork.